# Deriving equation with product formula for $1/\Gamma$ and Euler constant $\gamma$?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

In the above equation, how does the third line get derived from the second line? Not seeing how two $\prod$'s get derived... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He writes $~\displaystyle\exp\bigg(\sum a_n\bigg)=\prod e^{a_n},~$ then he mixes the two products term by term.

Cancellations occur. Also, $~e^{\ln N}=N.~$ The last product on the second row also has

a typo: It should be *n*, rather than *N*, in the denominator.